# how to have 2 columns with hyperlinks perfectly aligned?

Tags: asp.net

how to have 2 columns with hyperlinks perfectly aligned? This is what I have, for sure it is not the correct way to proceed

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Roxanne_RO_Monthly_Profitability" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 200px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">3- Roxanne R/O Monthly Profitability</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Roxanne_02_Special_Accounts" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 280px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">4- Roxanne 02 Special Accounts</asp:HyperLink>
<br /><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="Sales_Where_Work_Orders" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 200px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">5- Sales where Work Orders = 0 - Christina / Roxanne</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Sun_GL_Site" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 160px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">6- Sun GL Detail - Site Level - Part 1</asp:HyperLink>
```

result (4 and 6 are not aligned correctly)

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a table?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Roxanne_RO_Monthly_Profitability" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 200px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">3- Roxanne R/O Monthly Profitability</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
<td>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Roxanne_02_Special_Accounts" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 280px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">4- Roxanne 02 Special Accounts</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Sales_Where_Work_Orders" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 200px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">5- Sales where Work Orders = 0 - Christina / Roxanne</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
<td>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Sun_GL_Site" runat="server" Target="_CrystalReports" Style="margin-left: 160px" NavigateUrl="~/CrystalReports.aspx">6- Sun GL Detail - Site Level - Part 1</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```